# Django Logging - How to remove SQL query in logging file

Tags: django, logging, django-logging

I try to make Django Logging to log error from server. Now my code:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(PROJECT_LOCAL_URL, 'mylog.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

When I check `mylog.log`, it have too many sql queries string - `SELECT FROM`, which I want not to see. How can I config this?

[image]

How can I remove all sql queries in logging file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Database queries are logged by a [`django.db.backends`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) logger. Assuming you still want `DEBUG` level logging everywhere else then you need to specifically define a rule for this logger to ignore `DEBUG` logging:

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'WARNING',   # DEBUG will log all queries, so change it to WARNING.
        'propagate': False,   # Don't propagate to other handlers
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But change level into WARNING to Database queries, it sounds like not reasonable?

Comment: You could use level `INFO` instead, which is the next level up from `DEBUG`. It depends on how much you want to log.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke. Pick you the best answer!